# How to take store and restore sqlite database from Google drive in android studio when user it not automatic backup and restore

Tags: android, sqlite, cloud

I want my users to be able to store backup and restore Sqlite database from Google Cloud.I have searched and have not found any satisfactory answer so any help is greatly appreciated.